# JS: Group an array of object by specific field into section list

Tags: javascript

I have such data:

```
const data = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'River',
    address: 'Terminal A',
    type: 'OTHER',
    code: null,
    targetArrivalStep: 30,
    disabled: true,
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'Afer',
    address: 'Afer train station',
    type: 'TRAIN_STATION',
    code: 'MTS',
    targetArrivalStep: 0,
    disabled: false,
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    name: 'Fidel',
    address: 'HHH',
    type: 'OTHER',
    code: '',
    targetArrivalStep: 0,
    disabled: false,
  },
  {
    id: '5',
    name: 'Train station',
    address: 'Patrick str.',
    type: 'TRAIN_STATION',
    code: null,
    targetArrivalStep: 0,
    disabled: false,
  },
  {
    id: '7',
    name: 'qqq',
    address: 'qqq',
    type: 'BUS_STATION',
    code: null,
    targetArrivalStep: 60,
    disabled: false,
  },
];
```

I need to group it by `type`.

Here's the desired output:

```
const res = [
  {
    type: 'OTHER',
    data: [
      {
        id: '1',
        name: 'River',
        address: 'Terminal A',
        type: 'OTHER',
        code: null,
        targetArrivalStep: 30,
        disabled: true,
      },
      {
        id: '3',
        name: 'Fidel',
        address: 'HHH',
        type: 'OTHER',
        code: '',
        targetArrivalStep: 0,
        disabled: false,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    type: 'TRAIN_STATION',
    data: [
      {
        id: '2',
        name: 'Afer',
        address: 'Afer train station',
        type: 'TRAIN_STATION',
        code: 'MTS',
        targetArrivalStep: 0,
        disabled: false,
      },
      {
        id: '5',
        name: 'Train station',
        address: 'Patrick str.',
        type: 'TRAIN_STATION',
        code: null,
        targetArrivalStep: 0,
        disabled: false,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    type: 'BUS_STATION',
    data: [
      {
        id: '7',
        name: 'qqq',
        address: 'qqq',
        type: 'BUS_STATION',
        code: null,
        targetArrivalStep: 60,
        disabled: false,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Here's my solution:

```
const result = data.reduce((c, item) => {
  c[item.type] = c[item.type] || [];
  c[item.type].push(item);
  return c;
}, {});
```

I don't like the mutation of reduce arguments. Is there any other way to solve this task?

Comment: Why don't you like mutating the accumulator? This seems like a pretty reasonable way of accomplishing the task.

Comment: getting mutated is the very purpose / destiny of an accumulator

Comment: @PeterSeliger well it doesn't _have_ to be mutated, but it's certainly an option and in a lot of cases can be helpful.

Comment: @Nick ... Of cause I wanted to make a (counter) point. Especially since the OP without any further explanation just boldly states a personal belief / opinion / preference.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments, mutating the accumulator is perfectly reasonable: it is freshly created for this specific function call and only gets altered internally and without interruption. Seen from the outside, your solution is a pure function with no side effects.

**For the sake of the example though**, this is how you could rewrite your solution in a declarative fashion using some fancy destructuring magic:

```
const result = data.reduce((c, item) => ({...c, [item.type]:[...c[item.type] ?? [], item]}), {});
```

Explanation:

```
const result = data.reduce(
  (c, item) => ({              // Return a new object
    ...c,                      // Copy the previous object into it
    [item.type]: [             // Overwrite the current type group
      ...(c[item.type] ?? []), // Copy the old items of that group (or an empty array)
      item                     // Add the current item
    ] }),
  {}
);
```

It's pretty clear to me however that your original solution is the more readable and thus superior one.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying words. And thanks for the effort of showing an (ab)use case of spread syntax very close to the border of ridiculousness. The crazy kind of  storage address acrobatics would be even more obvious if one was replacing the obfuscating spread syntax with `Object.assign`.